# solid white debug light for CPU on new computer?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power, debug

I recently put together my first computer, but when I tried to turn it on the Ez-Debug led turned on solid white next to CPU. The CPU, GPU and case fans are all working, as are some leds. I looked around some forums and most people say check the CPU power cable, so I reset that and that didn't work. I tried checking my motherboard manual to see what exactly a 'solid white' LED meant next to CPU, but from what I saw it doesn't tell me the meaning of the colors.

The monitor doesn't detect anything so I can't see BIOS if it's up.

I have a [**MSI Z270-A pro**](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z270-A-PRO.html#productFeature-section) ([Manual Download](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z270-A-PRO.html#down-manual)) motherboard and I'm using the [**Intel I-5 7600k**](https://ark.intel.com/products/97144/Intel-Core-i5-7600K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz) CPU and a COrsair CX-M 550w PSU

I knew I'd have problems setting up my first PC but this is disheartening, so any suggestions would be very much appreciated. ^_^

Comment: Are you sure you wired it correctly? Do you have the ATX as well as the CPU power connector connected? Going by the manual there should be multiple LEDs one for CPU, DRAM, VGA and Boot each. As per the manual on page 21 they should stay turned on. There is no further information available what actually is wrong short of it's not working or not properly detected. You should make sure that the CPU is installed correctly (the lever on the side has to be all the way down and the "special" edge has to be oriented properly).

Comment: Yeah, I tried reconnecting the ATX and CPU power but no luck. Only the CPU is lit up. The lever is all the way down. On reconnecting the PSU to the CPU i noticed the pins do not match the holes. Like if the pins were square-circle-circle-square the holes are circle-square-square-circle, does that matter? It still connects fine and the CPU fan turns on.

Comment: is the CPU seated correctly? On my current build I kinda messed it up and bent some pins - its hard to see

Comment: See page 21 of the manual - there these 4 LEDs what you're talking about? If so, which is lit?

Comment: Consider taking some photos of the setup and especially the connector you're unsure about and the port you're plugging it into. You can upload it to a service like [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and link them.

Comment: @Seth Ok, I followed your instructions and checked out the CPU seating and was going to take some pictures. I noticed half the pins on my motherboard where the CPU goes are all laying down. Is it suppose to look like this? [link](http://imgur.com/a/Rwm6p)
Granted this might be a stupid question, as they are bent, but it's perfectly half side of the CPU so I didn't know if maybe the Z270-A pro is suppose to look like this or not. >_>
If so I'll be glad, because that's a problem I can solve without returning stuff randomly. [link](http://imgur.com/a/YC3pF) here's another pic.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from power there are 3 crucial components - CPU, RAM, Graphics.

Start with the basics:

- If you have onboard graphics available (you do), use it by removing discreet graphics.
- If you can, use only 1 sick of RAM in 'slot 1' (`DIMMA2` in your case)
- Remove all other components.

Ensure that your CPU is oriented correctly, and fully 'locked in' - the lever needs to hook under.

Ensure that the RAM is oriented correctly and fully 'locked in' - do not flip the catches up, but rather press on the RAM so that the catches flip up as a side effect.

Hopefully this will get you to POST, then start adding components.